# sql query to get difference of sum over two columns spread across two tables grouped by month

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a query to get difference of sum over two columns spread across two tables grouped by month.

Schema:

**TableA**

```
mass numeric,
weight numeric
sampleDt date
```

**TableB**

```
mass numeric,
weight numeric,
sampleDt date
```

**Sample Data for Table A**

```
100|200|2017-01-03
10 |20 |2017-01-05
200|400|2017-12-23
```

**Sample Data for Table B**

```
10   | 20   | 2017-01-20
10   | 20   | 2017-01-21
100  | 200  | 2017-12-12
2    | 4    | 2017-06-12
```

**Expected Output**

```
Month,Year |AMassTotal |AWeightTotal |BMassTotal |BWeightTotal |AMassTotal-BMassTotal

Jan,17 | 110 | 220 | 20 | 40 | 90
Jun,17 | 0   | 0   | 2  | 4  | -2
Dec,17 | 200 | 400 |100 |200 | 100
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? See, you have already got two product specific answers. Don't waste other users time writing answer for other products than the one used.

Comment: I am using postgres

Comment: Could you not do something like this: "SELECT CASE WHEN a.Month is null then b.Month ELSE a.month END, a.AMassTotal - b.BMassTotal FROM Table A a OUTER JOIN Table B b ON a.Month = b.Month"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a full outer join and a group by:

```
select to_char(sampledt, 'yyyy-mm') as month_year,
       coalesce(sum(a.mass),0) as a_mass_total, 
       coalesce(sum(a.weight),0) as a_weight_total, 
       coalesce(sum(b.mass),0) as b_mass_total, 
       coalesce(sum(b.weight),0) as b_weight_total,
       coalesce(sum(a.mass),0) - coalesce(sum(b.mass),0) as mass_total_diff
from table_a a
  full join table_b b using (sampledt)
group by to_char(sampledt, 'yyyy-mm');
```

If you want year and month in separate columns, you can use:

```
select extract(year from sampledt) as year, 
       extract(month from sampledt) as month, 
       coalesce(sum(a.mass),0) as a_mass_total, 
       coalesce(sum(a.weight),0) as a_weight_total, 
       coalesce(sum(b.mass),0) as b_mass_total, 
       coalesce(sum(b.weight),0) as b_weight_total,
       coalesce(sum(a.mass),0) - coalesce(sum(b.mass),0) as mass_total_diff
from table_a a
  full join table_b b using (sampledt)
group by extract(year from sampledt), extract(month from sampledt)
order by 1,2;
```

Except for the `to_char()` function the above is ANSI standard SQL.

Online example: http://rextester.com/YAN23912

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This works in **`SQL Server`**:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), sampleDt, 0)+','+CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,sampleDt) AS VARCHAR) [Month,Year]
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Tab=1 THEN mass END),0) AMassTotal 
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Tab=1 THEN weight END),0) AWeightTotal 
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Tab=2 THEN mass END),0) BMassTotal 
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Tab=2 THEN weight END),0) BWeightTotal 
    ,ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN D.Tab=1 THEN mass END)-SUM(CASE WHEN D.Tab=2 THEN mass END),0) [AMassTotal-BMassTotal]
FROM(
    SELECT 1 AS Tab,* FROM TableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,* FROM TableB
    )D
GROUP BY LEFT(DATEPART(MONTH,sampleDt),3)+DATEPART(YEAR,sampleDt)

select CONVERT(CHAR(3), GETDATE(), 0)
```

SQL Fiddle Demo: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30c77/7)

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: @jarlh, the answer was updated.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL

```
SELECT TB.`Month,Year`,
IFNULL(AMassTotal,0),
IFNULL(AWeightTotal,0),
IFNULL(BMassTotal,0),
IFNULL(BWeightTotal,0),
(IFNULL(AMassTotal,0)-IFNULL(BMassTotal,0)) AS 'AMassTotal-BMassTotal' 
FROM
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sampleDt,'%M,%Y') AS `Month,Year`,
SUM(CASE WHEN mass IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE mass END) AS AMassTotal, 
SUM(CASE WHEN weight IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE weight END) AS AWeightTotal
From TableA
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(sampleDt,'%M,%Y')
) AS TA
RIGHT JOIN 
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(sampleDt,'%M,%Y') AS `Month,Year`,
SUM(CASE WHEN mass IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE mass END) AS BMassTotal, 
SUM(CASE WHEN weight IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE weight END) AS BWeightTotal
FROM TableB
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(sampleDt,'%M,%Y')
) AS TB
ON TA.`Month,Year`=TB.`Month,Year`
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a6e24/22

Comment: Very product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: I maybe wrong but the question  was tagged with 'postgresql'.